# Install mono on Ubuntu without IDE

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I know how to install mono on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
# or
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

This page also explains how to install mono on Ubuntu: http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu

**But all those installations install the IDE as well. How can I install mono so that I can only run applications?** I do not want to install the IDE I just want to run mono applications.

Comment: Mono (`mono-devel`, `mono-complete`, etc..) does **not** contain an IDE, now if you are including the MonoDevelop IDE that is a different story, just do not  include the `monodevelop` package.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I installed `mono-develop` and that gave me an IDE.The following installations will not install an IDE:

```
apt-get install mono-devel
```

Or

```
apt-get install mono-complete
```

Or

```
apt-get install mono-runtime
apt-get install libmono-SYSTEM*
```

I though that `mono-develop` and `mono-devel` where the same and assume that mono-complete was everything including IDE.